# Why does free-spacing mode stop negative lookbehind from working?

Tags: ruby, regex

Consider the following Ruby code:

```
/(?<!big )dog/.match('I have a big dog.')        # => nil
```

Now, I'm going to enable free-spacing mode:

```
/(?x)(?<!big )dog/.match('I have a big dog.')        # => #<MatchData "dog">
```

Why does this happen, and how can I enable free-spacing mode without breaking my negative lookbehinds?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
/(?x)(?<!big )dog/.match('I have a big dog.')
#           ^
```

Note that you have a whitespace after `big`. Since it's the extended mode, the whitespace is ignored.

You have [some options](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.3/Regexp.html#class-Regexp-label-Free-Spacing+Mode+and+Comments):

- Use a pattern such as `\s` or `\p{Space}`.
- Use escaped whitespace such as `\`, i.e. a space preceded by a
  backslash.
- Use a character class such as `[ ]`.

For example:

```
/(?x)(?<!big\s)dog/.match('I have a big dog.')
# => nil
```

Comment: Disabling it in a particular sub expression might also be an option: `/(?x)(?-x:(?<!big ))dog/`

Comment: More options to match a space: `\x20` (hex) and `\040` (octal)